# Abstract type as parameter in method (.net, c#)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following method which I use to fill a DropDownList-Control.

```
protected void LoadDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable<A> source)
{
    ddl.DataSource = source;
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

My question is, can I make the method more abstract so that it can also take IEnumerables of type B?

Comment: What is type B? Also, it would be helpful if you could provide the entire class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
protected void LoadDropDownList<T>(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable<T> source) { 
    ...
```

See [also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: It might also be a good idea to insist that type `T` derives from some super class that has the `DataSource` property and a method called `DataBind()`.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention that.  It's not required, but if you're going to write code that can load anything into the list, they're going to have to implement some common base class.  You would add `where T : SomeBaseClass` after the `)` and before the `{`.

Comment: Thanks! Why does LoadDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable<T> source) not work?

Comment: Because that says you want an `IEnumerable` that can enumerate `T`s, where `T` is a class.  You need the `<T>` before the parameter list to indicate that `T` is a type parameter.  Refer to the link I gave in my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void LoadDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable source) {
     ddl.DataSource = source;
     ddl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: In other words, drop strong types altogether? :/